# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Но когда в концертном зале Пермской краевой филармонии одна за другой сменялись зарубежные делегации – из Узбекистана, Украины, Белоруссии, Польши, Чехии, Германии, Франции и др., подумалось: «Заслужили».

Правильно ли я расставила знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении лучше применить вставную конструкцию (два тире): Но когда в концертном зале Пермской краевой филармонии одна за другой сменялись зарубежные делегации - из Узбекистана, Украины, Белоруссии, Польши, Чехии, Германии, Франции и др., - подумалось: «Заслужили».

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Сравнить: В концертном зале Пермской краевой филармонии одна за другой сменялись зарубежные делегации – из Узбекистана, Украины, Белоруссии, Польши, Чехии, Германии, Франции и др.

Такие присоединительные конструкции характерны для конца предложения, но в составе сложного предложения трудно выразить перечислительную интонацию однородного ряда, в то же время это возможно сделать внутри вставки.

Для сравнения: Она повесила трубку – аппарат был рядом, – но ещё долго молчала.

Она повесила трубку – аппарат был рядом, – но ещё долго молчала.

Comment: Только я не очень поняла, почему для сравнения Вы привели два одинаковых примера? Наверное, в первом случае перед "но" должна была быть просто запятая?..

Comment: Это пример присоединительной конструкции в ПРОСТОМ предложении. Возможно еще такое сравнение: Но когда в концертном зале Пермской краевой филармонии одна за другой сменялись зарубежные делегации – из разных стран, подумалось: «Заслужили». Здесь вместо ряда одно слово (авторское обособление), и такой вариант можно "встроить" в сложное предложение (одно тире).

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что тут после "но" нужна запятая, потому что "когда в концертном зале..." - это вводное предложение, выделяемое запятыми. То есть получается "Но, когда в концертном зале Пермской краевой филармонии...". Дальше Вы все знаки препинания расставили правильно.
Пример аналогичной расстановки запятых в песне Вертинского:

*Ваш любовник скрипач. Он седой и горбатый,

Он вас дико ревнует, не любит и бьет,

Но, когда он играет концерт Сарасате,

Ваше сердце, как птица, летит и поет.*